# NCurses like library for haskell that runs on both Windows and Unix?

Tags: haskell, console, cross-platform, ncurses

I have a little program that is multi-threaded.  I'm tired of the output ending up cropping up within my input. I would like to use some type of library that will move me beyond the console model of the glass teletype.

The library I know (of) is ncursed which I can get to run under linux, but have never gotten working on windows.  I get stuck in dependency hell and can never get the D**m thing to compile.

I also have played with some GUI libraries that are nice, but I *really* don't want to have to reimplemented all the logic of line breaks, scrolling and even echoing characters by hand.

Is there a nice library with decent Haskell bindings that would let me set up a screen with an input area and an output area without requiring more programming time to create the the actual thing I'm writing?

Comment: Have you tried vty-ui: https://github.com/jtdaugherty/vty-ui ? It also has a nice [documentation](http://jtdaugherty.github.io/vty-ui/manuals/vty-ui-users-manual-1.9.pdf) with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposedly it is possible to make `hscurses` work on Windows, using PDCurses.  This page goes into detail: *[Installing hscurses on Windows](https://medium.com/@NightRa/installing-hscurses-on-windows-830532d3268a)*. You might be able to use a similar procedure for the ncurses MinGW port (see [ncurses FTP](http://invisible-mirror.net/archives/ncurses/win32/) for DLLs).

The lower-level package *[System.Console.ANSI](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ansi-terminal-0.5.0/docs/System-Console-ANSI.html)* is said to work with Windows, but that is not what was requested: *too* low-level.

A comment points to *[jtdaugherty/vty-ui](https://github.com/jtdaugherty/vty-ui)*, but looking at its [readme](https://github.com/jtdaugherty/vty-ui/blob/master/README) and source, I see nothing that hints it is cross-platform. Rather, it talks about *terminal emulators*.